# range() и вещественные числа

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
a = list(range(-4, 4, 2))
print(a)

b = list(range(-4, 15, 4))
print(b)

c = list(range(-200, 100, 60))
print(c)
```

Нужен список вещественных чисел переменной d как у остальных?

```
d = list(range(-25.1, 24.2, 2.4)) 
print(d)

s = int(24.2)
print(range(s))
```

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267226/range-for-floats

Comment: @mkkik Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: уточните суть вопроса, сейчас у вас просто ошибка - интерпретатор не может вещественное число преобразовать в целочисленное, это и естественно, это разные типы

Comment: В модуле numpy есть функция arange, которая принимает не целые числа. Если в Вашей программе много численных вычислений, то можно потянуть numpy- это удобно и производительно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как насчёт такого варианта?

http://ideone.com/rtLsh9

```
d = [num / 10 for num in range(-251, 242, 24)]
print(d)
```

Заодно проблемы с точностью решает.

Comment: Кстати, очень хороший вариант. Если решение нужно только для чисел с заранее заданным числом знаков после запятой, то этот вариант объективно лучше того, который предложил я. Но зато мой универсальнее :)

Answer (score 2):

Согласно официальной документации, аргументами range могут быть только целые числа:

> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers (either built-in **int** or any object that implements the `__index__` special method)

Подозреваю, что это было сделано намеренно - range обычно используется для циклов и поэтому должен работать максимально быстро. А возможность работать с вещественными числами, как мне кажется, его бы ощутимо замедлила.

Вы можете предварительно привести аргументы к целым числам:

```
d = list(range(int(-25.1), int(24.2), int(2.4)))
```

Но при этом они, что очевидно, будут округлены, и вы получите приблизительный результат.

Как вариант, вы можете использовать count из модуля itertools, но тогда вам придётся самостоятельно отслеживать, чтобы элементы не пересекли верхнюю границу:

```
from itertools import count

d_cnt = count(-25.1, 2.4)

d = []

for nd in d_cnt:
    if nd < 24.2:
        d.append(nd)
    else:
        break

print(d)
```

Либо вы можете написать альтернативный вариант range, который будет работать на вещественных числах.